# Lightweight Javascript Responsive Positioning Library

Tags: css-position, javascript

I am looking for a responsive positioning library for easily placing many elements in different positions on a HTML slide. Sometimes elements will need horizontal or vertical alignment, generally alignment needs to be relative to another element,

Sometimes I want alignment to be say 30px from the left of a panel or positioned 25% from the panel bottom line.

I need a little more then just vertical centering, we need flexible positioning of multiple items, so that they stay proportionally relative to either parent or sibling elements and for it work inside of a responsive container so that it can be viewed on mobile phone or desktop

One of my team members has written some code to position various elements in a responsive slideshow, the slideshow works on different devices.

```
function CalculatePosition(slide) {
    var body = $(slide).find('.bodySection');
    var playBtn = $(slide).find('.playButton');
    var skipBtn = $(slide).find('.skipButton');
    var videoContainer = $(slide).find('.video-container');
    var ytPlayer = $(slide).find('#ytplayer');
    var middle = $(slide).find('.middle');
    if (playBtn.length>0)
        $(playBtn).css({ marginTop: ($(body).height() - $(playBtn).height()) / 2 + "px", marginLeft: "-" + $(playBtn).width() / 2 + "px" });
    if (videoContainer > 0)
        $(videoContainer).css({ marginTop: ($(window).height() - $(ytPlayer).height()) / 2 + "px" });
    if (skipBtn > 0)
        $(skipBtn).css({ top: $(ytPlayer).height() / 2 + "px", marginTop: "-" + $(skipBtn).height() / 2 + "px" });
    if (middle > 0)
        $(middle).css({ paddingTop: ($(body).height() - $(middle).height()) / 2 + "px" });
}
```

I have looked around for a library that would make this a lot cleaner?

I would be interested in either a lightweight library that does something like this.

```
 $(playBtn).verticalCenterTo($(body));
// or
$(body).verticalCenter($(playBtn));
```

or a library that achieves the same thing using attribute notation

```
<div class='bodySection'>
   <span class='playButton' align-relative-to='bodySection' align-type='vertical-center' />
   <span class='stopButton' align-relative-to='playButton' align-position='right 20px' />
</div>
```

Comment: I have just come across http://jqueryui.com/position which I think will be my answer, I do welcome better solutions though

Answer (score 0):

If you only need vertical positioning why not use a CSS only solution such as the display: table-cell technique descfibed here: http://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/vertical-centering/table-cell.php

If you need to center with respect to different parents you can use class switching to get the desired effect. This is much faster than calculating it using JS.

Not sure if this does everything you need. Leave a comment if I misuderstood your question.

Comment: I need a little more then just vertical centering, we need flexible positioning of multiple items, so that they proportionally move relative to either parent or sibling elements and for that to work inside of a responsive container so that it can be viewed on mobile phone or desktop

Comment: And, what do you mean by Class Switching?